# How to unzip several files

Tags: python-2.7, gzip

I have over 300 files that are named like this:

dumpADS-2017-01-01_0029.log.gz

the only difference for these files are the dates.
Here an example, the first file is from January 8, while the second is from January 9:

```
dumpADS-2017-01-08_0029.log.gz
dumpADS-2017-01-09_0029.log.gz
```

What i am trying to do is to unzip these files and put the data in arrays so that i can work with the data. My question is how is it possible to unzip all these files without having to repeat the same command 300 times and change the date manually. What i did to unzip the data and to put the data into an array is the following:

```
import numpy as np
t=np.genfromtxt('X:\ADS2017\dumpADS-2017-01-02_0029.log.gz',dtype = np.str,delimiter=",")
```

but this is very slow when running the program and as said before if i do it like this i would have to write this 300 times with a different filename.
Is it somehow possible to use a for loop or what other possibilities are there to get this done?

Comment: @SiHa i edited my first post and included my programs, i hope this makes it a little clearer

Comment: Better :) Still not entirely clear, though. There's a lot of code there, you should try to condense your problem down to a [mcve], and explain exactly what your problem is. Are you just trying to make your code run faster, or is it something else?

Comment: @SiHa I changed the question because i'm struggling with two different things here and asking both as one question makes it less clear

Comment: Much better, but still not *really* answerable. Of course you can use a `for` loop, yes. But without knowing precisely how the names differ between files, no-one can do it for you. You could use [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to create a list of filenames and iterate through that or you could use a regex to filter a directory list, or... There are may possible solutions. Sorry if it seems like I'm just being awkward - I'm really not trying to be.

Comment: Are all of these `.gz` files in a single directory?

Comment: @heyiamt no they are all in ADS2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing to do here would be to use `os` to loop through the file names in the `ADS2017` directory. If you're going to be loading data into memory and perform analysis, it may be worthwile to unzip everything first, and then ready in the numpy arrays from the extracted files.

An example is

```
import os
import gzip
import numpy as np

dirn = 'ADS2017'
unzipped_dirn = 'ADS2017_unzipped' 

if not os.path.exists(unzipped_dirn):
    os.mkdir(unzipped_dirn)

# Unzip files.
for fname in os.listdir(dirn):
    full_fname = os.path.join(dirn, fname)
    with gzip.open(full_fname, 'rb') as f:
        content = f.read()

    new_full_fname = os.path.join(unzipped_dirn, fname.replace('.gz', ''))
    with open(new_full_fname, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(content)

# Load files.
ts = []
for fname in os.listdir(unzipped_dirn):
    full_fname = os.path.join(unzipped_dirn, fname)
    ts.append(np.genfromtxt(full_fname,dtype = np.str,delimiter=","))
```

Comment: there seems to be a problem because the files are much smaller after unpacking then they should be. Also i get the following message for every single line:  Line #2638590 (got 3 columns instead of 1)

Comment: @Kenny that's because the gzip was being opened as an unzipped file. i fixed the code. does that result in expected file sizes after extraction?

Answer (score 0):

The concatenation of valid gzip files is also a valid gzip file. You can simply (in Unix/Linux as an example) `cat dumpADS-*.log.gz > all.log.gz` and read or decompress that one gzip file, `all.log.gz`. The shell will put the arguments in sorted order, which will put them in date order in the concatenated file.